# How to read characters Count "Text Length" for Excel cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**I want to read the count of characters for a cell and set it to another cell.**

Could you please tell me what is the function "Formula" to do that?.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

=LEN(A1)

Where A1 is the Cell whose text length you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use this function.

`len(CELL)`